# I don't know priority of some lines OOP

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have problem at my code I don't know priority of some lines,

I want to make (Game guess the number),
have user and computer player both have (10) points,
so the user input number form 1 to 2, if (user input) == (number of guess), 
will -1 from computer points(10) = 9, and vice versa,
so my problem at the points, after first time user input number it Become as they were automatically(10),
sorry about my english so bad.
at below my code, I hope any one help me thank you.

```
from random import randint as any_number

class Game():
    def __init__(self, name, number, points):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.points = points

    def score(self, other):
        guess = any_number(1, 2)
        if self.number == guess:
            print('{} your are correct'.format(self.name))
            other.points = other.points - 1
        else:
            print('{} your are incorrect'.format(self.name))
        print('{} points is ({}) and {} points is ({})'.format(self.name, self.points, other.name, other.points))


while True:
    user1 = int(input('Guess a number from 1 to 2: '))
    computer = any_number(1, 2)

    p1 = Game('Player1', user1, 10)       #  <---- my problem here 
    p2 = Game('player2', computer, 10)    #  <---- my problem here

    if type(user1) == int:
        p1.score(p2)
        print('================================================= ')
        p2.score(p1)
    else:
        print('your input is Error')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think your question is clear at the moment. Is it possible that you can [edit] your question and better explain what you are asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understood your issue, the problem is that you are creating a new instance of type Game in every turn, so try this:

```
from random import randint as any_number

class Game():
    def __init__(self, name, number, points):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.points = points

    def score(self, other):
        guess = any_number(1, 2)
        if self.number == guess:
            print('{} your are correct'.format(self.name))
            other.points = other.points - 1
        else:
            print('{} your are incorrect'.format(self.name))
        print('{} points is ({}) and {} points is ({})'.format(self.name, self.points, other.name, other.points))

p1 = Game('Player1', user1, 10)
p2 = Game('player2', computer, 10) 

while True:
    user1 = int(input('Guess a number from 1 to 2: '))
    computer = any_number(1, 2)

    if type(user1) == int:
        p1.score(p2)
        print('================================================= ')
        p2.score(p1)
    else:
        print('your input is Error')
```